# Print shipping label to thermal printer

Tags: php, printing

I have my own eCommerce website www.foo.com. Basically when a customer buys something from my site, I would be processing the order and later shipped to the customer all from the back end of the site. I have implemented a button whereby once the button ("Print Label") is clicked, the site should send the shipping, billing and other data I deem necessary to the thermal printer to print the shipping label.

Now this is my problem. I do not own a thermal printer as of now (going to purchase it soon). As far as I know, these thermal printers do come with a shipping label creator some sort of. Lets assume that I have "designed" a shipping label which I wanna use or maybe use a built-in template in the provided software.

Now how do I send the data as described above from the php page (button which I named as "Print Label") to the "designed" shipping label template and have it printed to my thermal printer as a properly formatted shipping label?

I guess I need to use C# or some language. I have no idea what to do or if it can be done?

Kindly advise please? Thank you!!

Comment: We do something very similar to that using PHP, but of course, other languages could be used instead. We have a Zebra thermal printer (black and white only, though color printers are available too), but there are MANY other printer manufacturers available -- depends on your budget and other factors. See [this site](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) for an example. The data on the left is the coding used to create the label (is sent to the printer as a string) and the label on the right is the example label generated from the code. You can get their API info as well to know what the codes mean.

Comment: Ok i purchased my thermal printer already. Just got to know that it supports TSPL and not ESC/POS. So any idea how do I move on from here pls?

Comment: Not sure, don't know what printer model was purchased, and I've never used TSPL (TSPL is not mentioned in the question), but looking at [this API reference](http://www.kroyeuropedownload.com/English_User_Manuals/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming_Jan_2017.pdf) (I'm sure there are other API references online elsewhere, might also come with the printer), just a different command set used to create labels. What I work with is ZPL, which is Zebra's own programming language.

Comment: Hi Paul, just like ZPL, TSPLis another language. I realised that all the industrail thermal printers use TSPL. There is full documentation of over a few 100 pages. Wished that my printer at ZPL or ESC/POS. However my printer supports PDF printing very very well. So on a side note, I just have to create my shipping label via mPDF, FPDF etc and print via PDF.

Comment: I realize that on TSPL, I googled that, I added a link in my previous comment to an example API reference that I found.